# How can i add values in array and the show it as one string?

Tags: c, mplab

I need to add same values on array and then to see it as one string.

```
 char txt[33] = "";

 for (int i=0; i<4; i++)   
 {
     txt[i]="A";    
 }

LCDPutStr(txt,25);
```

I get `4` characters but they are strange symbols. I need to take `"AAAA"`.

Comment: Turn on all warnings and make the compiler report them as errors. If this is your actual code and it passes compilation, it means your compiler settings aren't what they should be.

Comment: tip: initialize your strings with `{0}`, instead of `""`, to set all the elements to `0`, instead of only the first element!

Comment: @Lanting ; Aaaanndd, what's the purpose of this useless thing ? I mean, a string is an array of char terminated by a specific value (\0).
In order to have a valid string, all you need is to have \0 at the right place. If you do some custom operation, it's up to you to not forget about the terminating \0, but initialising all the array with \0 is useless since you should alway take care of the final \0. In the worst case, you risk to forget about the \0 in one of your custom function and the filled array will cover this mistake, instead of crashing rigth away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If LCDPutStr expects a string (as its name suggests), then you need to null terminate your string:

```
char txt[33]="";
for (int i=0;i<4;i++)   
{
    txt[i]='A';
}
txt[4] = '\0';

LCDPutStr(txt,25);
```

Comment: What if i want to use string? Example "ABC"

Comment: I don't know of the second parameter of LCDPutStr, but you have two common way : either you just give the constant string "LCDPutStr("ABC", 2)" or you use strcpy in order to copy "ABC" in txt.

Comment: care to explain the -1 ?

Answer (score 2):

1) use `'A'`, single quote, in stead of the double quote;

2) terminate the string with a `'\0'`: `text[i]= '\0';`

Summary:

```
 char txt[33] = "";
 int i;

 for (i=0; i<4; i++)   
 {
     txt[i]='A';    
 }
 txt[i]='\0';

 LCDPutStr(txt,25);
```

(I moved `int i` to before the loop so it is available afer the loop to put the terminator there.)